# How to add 2 vectors in python with __add__ method?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to add two vectors using the method **add**

I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
class vector(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def __add__(self, *other):
        a = [arg + other for arg, other in
                        list(zip(self.args, self.other))]
        return vector(*a)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.args

v1 = vector(1, 4, 8, 9),
v2 = vector(5, 3, 2, 1)
```

produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    v1 +v2

File "C:/Users/Rouizi/Desktop/b.py", line 8, in __add__
    list(zip(self.args, self.other))]
AttributeError: 'vector' object has no attribute 'other'
```

Comment: I do not believe you can deref other. The signature states its an object.

Comment: did you try def __add__(self, other) return vector(*other)

Comment: also, self.other should probably just be other... self.other doesn't look stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have slightly modified your code. Follow comments.

```
# class names should use CapWords convention (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
class Vector:

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    # addition is normally a binary operation between self and other object
    def __add__(self, other):
        # other.args is the correct analog of self.args
        a = [arg1 + arg2 for arg1, arg2 in zip(self.args, other.args)]
        return self.__class__(*a)

    # __repr__ and __str__ must return string
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ + str(self.args)


v1 = Vector(1, 4, 8, 9)
v2 = Vector(5, 3, 2, 1)

print(v1)
print(v2)
print(v1 + v2)
print(v1 + v1 + v2 + v2)
```

Output:

```
Vector(1, 4, 8, 9)
Vector(5, 3, 2, 1)
Vector(6, 7, 10, 10)
Vector(12, 14, 20, 20)
```

Also I use `self.__class__` instead of `Vector` and `self.__class__.__name__` instead of `"Vector"` - this allows to change class name without changing its code.

Comment: Using `self.__class__.__name__` (or to save underscores, `type(self).__name__`) in the `__repr__` is useful even if the class itself has a stable name. It makes the `__repr__` subclass friendly; when you define `class SpecialVector(Vector):`, you don't need to override `__repr__` unless the signature for `__init__` changed; it'll seamlessly use the parent's `__repr__` while producing a string based on the child class's name.

Comment: @Yacine Rouizi this post seems rather complete and does work in my ide. Can we mark this as the accepted answer?